# UI Recorder template not found in instruments

Tags: ios, user-interface, automation, recorder, ios-ui-automation

I have installed xcode4 and used profiling for leaks and allocations, etc. However, I don't find the new UI Recorder template in instruments under iOS however I find a template named Automation.  Please let me know how to enable UI Recorder template in instruments for xcode 4 and also any idea what is this Automation template for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no UI Recorder template for iOS applications, it can't be done. The Automation template is for automated UI unit tests. It runs a JavaScript test script that you put together that is able to drive the UI and record successes or failures. You can find details about UI Automation in the [Instruments Users Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW75).

It helps a lot to read the documentation first and then ask specific questions later, when you don't understand something in the documentation or something doesn't work as expected. If you don't read the documentation, you'll just get answers where people either reiterate the documentation to you, or point you to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was browsing quickly on this particular doc unlike others that I read from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead you can record the user actions of the iOS simulator.

Make sure that the 'Enable access for assistive devices' setting is enabled in your Universal Access pane of System Preferences.
In instruments, just choose the 'UI Recorder' template (Mac OS X).
Start the iOS simulator and connect it to instruments by attaching the 'iPhone simulator' process in the 'choose target' selection box.
Press 'Record'.

Welcome!

Comment: You can't profile an iOS App by attaching instruments to the simulator process. That's not a solution for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've just tried Rolands suggestion below and it works - not perfectly, it misses to play some recorded interactions, but it works and creates an editable script! I'm using Xcode 4.6.2, Instruments 4.6 and running iPhone 6.1 Simulator.